# Alfresco 3.0. Recovering from contentstore.deleted?

Tags: alfresco

I have an Alfresco 3.0 instance on a server. But I'm not even a novice with it. Somehow all contents were deleted. They now seems to be in "special" store: contentstore.deleted.

Is there any way to recover (at least) the files deleted in contentstore.deleted? Can I inspect the contents of the store and extract those files?

Best regards,
Manuel.

Comment: Do you really mean 3.0? That's pretty old. If you're on 3.4 or 3.5 then the answer's a bit easier, can you confirm which you're really on?

Comment: 3.0 it is. I'm not in the position to change that yet. But I would let the team know your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to alfresco explorer (use http://server/alfresco instead of /share)
- Login
- Click on the User Profile (that strange msn-looking icon)
- You will see this:
  [image: User Profile and Settings]
- Click on Manage Deleted Items
- Here you can recover the deleted items
- It looks like this (this is no screenshot of mine)
  [image: Deleted Items]

Comment: That didn't help. It appears empty.

Comment: There are several ways to delete content in Alfresco. Normally it will be archived and been seen in the Deleted Items. But you can also completely delete it, then it's not seen here.

Comment: This also works on Share (which is good as Explorer has been removed from current builds of Alfresco), with the slight change of using the "Trashcan" option in the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Alfresco 3.5 or later (currently that means 3.5 or a nightly build of 4.0), then it's really easy. Log into Share as an Admin, click the More (+) icon at the top, and then select "Trashcan". That'll let you see all the deleted nodes in the system, from the deleted content store, and you can undelete them

[image: Share Admin UI for the Trashcan]

Comment: In the web client, this is in profile (!) > Manage Deleted Items.

Comment: Unfortunately , I'm using 3.0.